# rename bigquery tablename

Tags: google-bigquery, rename

How to **rename table name** in bigquery table?

Comment: `ALTER TABLE mydataset.mytable RENAME TO mynewtable;`

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#renaming-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you can't rename an existing table in google big query. Instead, you can follow the copy process. You may refer the [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables)

Answer (score 0):

Here in a bigquery we need to **copy table with new name** and then you can delete existing table